# How would I access a field in a collection whos' key contains a space?

Tags: meteor

Data was imported from a csv into mongo. No practical to remove the space in the data.

Example:

```
{{#each item}}
    {{name}}
    {{"Transaction Number"}}
{{/each}}
```

The "Transaction Number" is the field name. Can place into a helper, but would like to use the #each.

```
Template.hello.helpers({
    item: function() {
        return Items.find()
    },
    counter: function () {
        return Session.get('counter');
    }
});
```

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe a transform could be helpful here, although ultimately you want to fix the field key to be valid IMO.

```
Items.find({}, {transform: function(doc) {
    doc.transactionNumber = doc['Transaction Number'];
    return doc;
}});
```

Then you should be able to access it within the template correctly:

```
{{#each item}}
    {{transactionNumber}}
{{/each}}
```

You can specify new variables as `doc.whateverYouLike` which can be quite useful when doing 'aggregate' queries like adding a variable that represents a field from another collection.

Comment: That worked. I liked that it is done in the query. Very useful.

Answer (score 1):

You could rely on this trick :

JS

```
Template.hello.helpers({
  transactionNumber: function(){
    return this["Transaction Number"];
  }
});
```

HTML

```
{{#each item}}
  {{name}}
  {{transactionNumber}}
{{/each}}
```

Comment: This works for each item? is that because 'this' becomes the data context of wherever it is called from? If that's the case I had no idea this was possible, interesting...